# oldLC object when creating package

Tags: r

I've just noticed whenever I build and reload a package, I have this new object "oldLC." It's never been there before, so why is it appearing now, and how can I make it stop? The only thing I can think of that has changed since the last time I made a package until now is that I installed the newest rstudio.

```
> load_all()
Loading tmp
> ls()
character(0)

Restarting R session...

> library(tmp)
> ls()
[1] "oldLC"
> oldLC
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tmp_0.1        roxygen2_3.1.0 devtools_1.4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] brew_1.0-6      codetools_0.2-8 digest_0.6.4    evaluate_0.5.1 
 [5] httr_0.2        memoise_0.1     parallel_3.0.2  Rcpp_0.11.0    
 [9] RCurl_1.95-4.1  stringr_0.6.2   tools_3.0.2     whisker_0.3-2
```

Comment: The same thing just happened to me...

Comment: I'm getting this too...

Comment: This slash devided locale entry. Is that normal on apple-darwin? I am getting locale entries like "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8" and so on for others LC. It is hard to troubleshoot as you did not supply in fact the code to replicate the behavior. Did you try to test it on another plathorm with same R version?

Comment: To move it forward, try to run R --vanilla directly from terminal window (do not use Rstudio) and then library(tmp);ls();sessionInfo() to see if it has anything to do with your session environment.

Comment: There really is no code to provide--just build and reload a package with rstudio. I did another with R --vanilla, and it does not create the oldLC object, so it only creates when I `cmd + shift + b`, ie, build and reload a package in rstudio. It also doesn't seem to be the `roxygenize` function but rather after the `R CMD INSTALL` step it appears. I also used roxygen to build the package in R --vanilla when it did not appear in my workspace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`oldLC` is a temporary object created by the "SessionBuild.cpp" script.

Here's the relevant snippet from [RStudio's GitHub page](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/session/modules/build/SessionBuild.cpp) that explains why it contains locale information:

> ```
>   // format the command to send to R
>   boost::format cmdFmt(
>      "suppressPackageStartupMessages("
>         "{oldLC <- Sys.getlocale(category = 'LC_COLLATE'); "
>         " Sys.setlocale(category = 'LC_COLLATE', locale = 'C'); "
>         " on.exit(Sys.setlocale(category = 'LC_COLLATE', locale = oldLC));"
>         " %1%; }"
>       ")");
> ```

I don't know why it's appearing with the most recent update or how to make it stop, but it's something the RStudio folks will want to fix in a future update.

Comment: I didn't even know rstudio put their source code on github. guess I should have looked there